# Can we let debugger to selectively pause a thread in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Can we let VS2008 debugger to selectively pause a thread in VS2008?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you stop on a breakpoint you can choose one or a few threads in the `Threads` window and `Freeze` them. When you need to run the paused threads again you need to choose them again in that `Threads` window and say `Thaw`.

Answer (score 1):

Best way I have come up with is a conditional breakpoint and manual ID's for the threads so I can break in the selected thread.